# imshow create new windows with opencv on ubuntu

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to show images from camera using cv2.imshow, but instead of updating it creates new windows.

This is the code

```py
import cv2

if __name__ == '__main__':

    roi_width = 300
    roi_height = 300

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret, original = cam.read()

        roi = original[0:roi_height, 0:roi_width]

        cv2.rectangle(original, (0, 0), (roi_width+5, roi_height+5), 5)

        cv2.imshow("original", original)
        cv2.imshow("roi", roi)

        k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        if k == ord('q'):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the result I got after 10 iterations

[image]

Comment: I tried your sample code and it does not create new windows. What versions of python and opencv do you have?

Comment: Conda version: 4.8.3
Python version: 3.7.7
OpenCV version: 4.3.0
Ubuntu: 20.04 LTS 64-bits

I tried with conda and python separated, but the result is same

Comment: Have you installed opencv with pip or did you build it from source? Is there any message or warning when you run the script from the console?

Comment: I installed the library opencv-contrib-python using pip. There isn't any message on console.

Comment: Apparently there is a bug, https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17827