# openCV imshow fails randomly

Tags: python, opencv

When I want to display an image, the `cv2.imshow()` fails randomly.

```py
import cv2

frame = cv2.imread('desk.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

cv2.imshow('test', frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Sometimes, I got the first and sometimes the second:
[image: imshow_fail] [image: imshow_success]

I'm sure that the data is correctly loaded because when I print the frame matrix, everything is ok. I also tried to convert picture to other format but the result is always the same, random.

```py
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.3.0'
# opencv-contrib-python is installed
```

Kernel informations: `Linux 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 GNU/Linux`

**Edit**: As Doch88 said, compiling from source solve my problem. Here my cmake command:

```sh
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
      -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
      -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
      -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_src/opencv_contrib/modules ../opencv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62940473/imshow-create-new-windows-with-opencv-on-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment111343490_62940473) with a similar problem, and according to [this issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17827) it is a bug:

> This issue cannot be fixed in OpenCV, the issue is related to Qt
> conflicts between the bundled Qt4 in the Python wheels and system
> Qt4/5 installations.

A way to solve it is probably to build OpenCV from source code.

Comment: Effectivelly, I'm also a Qt developer, so it is a very high probability. I try to compile from source and come back ;)

Comment: This issue could also be useful: https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/362 in the answers the owner of the opencv-python repository shows some proper workarounds to avoid this problem (including building the wheel from source)

Comment: By compiling from source everything is okay, I edit my answer with my compile line if it can be help some people, thank you very much